# How to re-index nodes using search API?

Tags: 8, search, cron

On exploring search_api.module file, there mentioned few hooks.Is there any practical demonstration how to use `search_api_index_reindex` hook?

Basically I'm trying to re-index nodes, after executing some operations. I tried the way, mentioned below, but didn't get any success. any help is really appreciated.

```
$conditions = [
    'status' => TRUE,
  ];
  $index_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('search_api_index');
  $indexes = $index_storage->loadByProperties($conditions);
  foreach ($indexes as $index_id => $index) {
    try {
          $num = $index->indexItems('-1');
         // print_r($num);
          \Drupal::logger('Reindexing processing...')->debug(print('reindexing done'));
    }catch (Exception $e) {
\Drupal::logger('custom benefits cron reindexing')->debug(print($e));
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to invalidate the index so it gets rebuilt, but that won't happen right away, only on a series of cron runs.

Comment: series of cron are set by increment of 1 hour. So, it means I have to wait for the last cron so that my data first get rebuilt? Is there any other alternative to re-index these nodes manually?

Comment: Manually? From the admin panel or using drush.https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/search-api/

Comment: Did you try [this way](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252988/how-to-force-search-api-to-reindex-a-node-an-entity)?