# How can I programmatically reindex Commerce products to AWS Elastic Search?

Tags: 8, commerce, search

I am using Drupal 8 Commerce module.

I am using Elastic Search on AWS platform.

From the Admin whenever product is saved, those changes are directly applied on Elastic Search server, but when I try with `$product->save()` it is not working 100%.

So if I have to update 10 products in Elastic Search how to achieve that programatically?

In particular, I have to update one field only. Because what is happening that, it will update that field value in database but not on Elastic Search.

I found this useful post for Node [How To Force Search API To Reindex a Node / an Entity](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252988/how-to-force-search-api-to-reindex-a-node-an-entity)

Comment: You'll need to describe how you're connecting Drupal8 to ES to get this answered. Custom integration? Search API ES connector? If you're not doing a custom integration, running drupal cron will probably trigger the re-indexing you're looking for.

Comment: Hi @ShawnConn using Elastic Connector module. Not any custom integration. Cron job is working as expected. But we want to do like when needed

Comment: If you're using the Search API integration, you could just call the cron handler `search_api_cron()` directly.

Comment: So does this will update any of the changes which I have in Drupal database but not in Elastic Search indexing?

Comment: Without knowledge of the ES connector, I can't say for sure. But if you're using Seach API / ES integration; and see that a manual cron job fixes the issue; then `search_api_cron()` will execute the same function as it does when cron is ran (minus all other cron hooks that fire in Drupal)

Comment: Can we run that command via CLI?

Comment: Nope it is not working as expected. It is not reflecting one field changed value to Elastic Search.

Comment: Please don't put Drupal and 8 into your question title. The whole site is about Drupal and the version tag is in the tags.

Answer (score 2):

So I have some updates answer relies in `search_api.module` file
function `search_api_entity_update`.

So I am able to achieve for one product. Can loop & do for multiple.

```
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\search_api\Plugin\search_api\datasource\ContentEntity;

$entity = Product::load(1); // Replace 1 with your product id.

$indexes = ContentEntity::getIndexesForEntity($entity);

if (!$indexes) {
  return;
}

foreach ($indexes as $index) {
  $index->trackItemsUpdated('entity:commerce_product', ['1:en']);
}
```

It works like a charm :)

Comment: So you hacked the code in the search_api.module?

Comment: Nope. I have take the reference and use it when ever it is required

Comment: Ah okay! It sounded a bit as if you where hacking the module. ^^